# Pandas regex split on characters and group

Tags: regex, pandas, split, regex-group

I've never got around to learning regex till now, but I'm trying to figure out how to use it in pandas with `Series.str.match(expression)` In order to split one column to make two new columns. (I know I can do this without regex)

examples of the column data are:

> True Grit {'Rooster Cogburn'}
>
> The King's Speech {'King George VI'}
>
> Biutiful {'Uxbal'}

Where there can be any number of strings greater than 1 in each of the two groupings. How can I extract two groups to result in `True Grit, Rooster Cogburn`?

Comment: can you post you desired data set?

Comment: If you haven't used http://www.regexr.com , it's a great tool to bang out regex quickly.

Comment: It's the `Additional Info` column of this `csv` dataset: https://www.aggdata.com/awards/oscar

Comment: Is @A-Za-z's solution - that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this dataframe

```
    col
0   True Grit {Rooster Cogburn}
1   The King's Speech {King George VI}
2   Biutiful {Uxbal}

df = df.col.str.extract('(.*)\s*{(.*)}', expand = True)
```

will return

```
    0                   1
0   True Grit           Rooster Cogburn
1   The King's Speech   King George VI
2   Biutiful            Uxbal
```

Comment: Perfect and saved me steps of adding/removing columns, thanks!